# Python script to output CSV of only duplicate records?

Tags: python, csv

I have a bunch of records like so:

```
uniqueIdHere1,2020-02-21T21:29:31Z,2020-03-25T20:44:29.810951Z2020-02-21 21:29:31.996,1582320571996
uniqueIdHere1,2020-02-21T21:29:31Z,2020-03-25T20:44:29.810951Z2020-02-21 21:29:31.996,1582320571996
uniqueIdHere1,2020-02-21T21:29:31Z,2020-03-25T20:44:29.810951Z2020-02-21 21:29:31.996,1582320571996
uniqueIdHere2,2020-02-21T21:29:31Z,2020-03-25T20:44:29.810951Z2020-02-21 21:29:31.996,1582320571996
uniqueIdHere3,2020-02-21T21:29:31Z,2020-03-25T20:44:29.810951Z2020-02-21 21:29:31.996,1582320571996
```

My goal is to have an `duplicatedRecords.csv` of only records that are duplicated by the ID column. Expected output:

```
uniqueIdHere1,2020-02-21T21:29:31Z,2020-03-25T20:44:29.810951Z2020-02-21 21:29:31.996,1582320571996
uniqueIdHere1,2020-02-21T21:29:31Z,2020-03-25T20:44:29.810951Z2020-02-21 21:29:31.996,1582320571996
uniqueIdHere1,2020-02-21T21:29:31Z,2020-03-25T20:44:29.810951Z2020-02-21 21:29:31.996,1582320571996
```

I don't really know Python, but was hoping to just have a little one off script. Attempted code a little bit:

```
with open('1.csv','r') as in_file, open('2.csv','w') as out_file:
    seen = set() # set for fast O(1) amortized lookup
    dupeSet = set() # dupe check for filtering serialized output data

    for line in in_file:
        if line not in seen and line not in dupeSet:
            seen.add(line)
        if line in seen and line in dupeSet:
            out_file.write(line)
```

Something like this, but it got messy and was hoping for a little help.

Comment: Are the duplicates always consecutive?

Comment: Are you looking for duplicate IDs?  Your example code looks for duplicate lines.

Comment: no, not always consecutive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach, which uses the pandas library to import the csv and select repeated id rows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('1.csv', names = ['id', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3'] )
counts = df['id'].value_counts()
df_output = df.loc[df['id'].isin(counts.index[counts > 1])]
df_output.to_csv('newfile.csv',index = False)
```

Comment: sorry, I don't know if I clarified. I still want the entire row to be in-tact. It seems like this is outputting 2020-02-22T02:45:00Z,,,. The CSVs don't have column headers btw

Comment: Hm - I changed it to a .loc in one line - did that improve the output?

Comment: Let me give it a shot

Comment: 2020-02-22T18:55:57Z,,, Hm.. same issue

Comment: what happens when you read in the csv to a df and print(df.head())?

Comment: A bunch of garbage gets printed out. The input csv doesn't have headers, is that a prob?

Comment: Sorry, my apologies.. Data in file is slightly skewed, let me fix. Might be my mistake!

Comment: I added made-up headers using names = ['id', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3'], so that shouldn't be the issue, but see if you can get it imported as ~4 columns in the .read_csv() line.

Comment: Hey thanks for this! It was good and I screwed up my merged csv data. This worked perfect

Answer (score 2):

If your data is in a dataframe, you can just use the duplicated method:

```
import pandas as pd
df = #some dataframe with an id column

duplicated_df = df[df.duplicated(subset = ['id'], keep = False)]
duplicated_df.to_csv('duplicatedRecords.csv')
```

Comment: Edit: you fixed this! disregard....For duplicated this will naturally check across all columns - you need to specify just the ID column for it to work like the poster wants it to (e.g. duplicated user id, but different data in the other cols)

Comment: Thanks @katardin I misread the filter the OP mentioned between data and expected output.

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't outputting correctly. Lots of random commas everywhere